# Laravel 5 get current datetime in MySQL format

Tags: laravel, datetime

In Laravel 5, how to get current DateTime in local time (without timezoning) and convert it to MySQL datetime?

Answer (score 2):

```
use Carbon\Carbon


$mytime =Carbon::now();
echo $mytime->toDateTimeString();
```

see this
[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Answer (score 1):

For current time you in your local timezone you can use carbon in laravel

```
Carbon::now('Asia/Dhaka')->toDateTimeString()
```

and you can use it in mysql.To get timezone list go here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: Because I want to get datetime (not only date), I use now():. This is the result with now() 2016-02-14 09:02:33.000000
3
UTC, But I want to get the time in my local time 16:02:33

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.2 and want to change MySQL timezone, you'll have to edit config/database.php and add this line

```
 'mysql' => [

    ... 

   'timezone' => '+01:00' 

 ],
```

To set current DateTime in your local time for your application, go to config/app.php, find timezone end replace 'UTC' to 'Asia/Dhaka'.